# Plot all columns in heatmap of dataframe

Tags: python

I have a expression matrix of two columns and 1400 rows. I wanted to plot a heatmap for the expression values. When I used the following code:

```
sns.heatmap(df2, cmap = 'magma')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I got heatmap [image] with some randomly selected columns. However, I wanted all 1400 columns to be plotted with labels, or the most expressed. What might be the conflict?

I am new to this so facing more of the problems. Any help is highly appreciated.